# Showing existence of solution by positive definiteness/convexity

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For a physics problem, I am considering the following problem:
I have a certain function, $S: \mathbb{R}^M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, of which the critical points, given by 
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial\lambda_{\gamma}}=0
$$
($\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^M$ so M equations, I denote a component of this vector by $\lambda_{\gamma}$). In fact, the critical points form an equation I am actually interested in. I want to prove that these equations have a unique, existing solution. The reference I am following, shows that 
$$
\sum_{\alpha,\beta}v_{\alpha}v_{\beta}\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial\lambda_{\alpha}\partial\lambda_{\beta}}>0¸
$$
i.e. S is positive definite in lambda. It then concludes that the equations thus have a unique, existing solution.

I am somewhat confused by this. I know of a theorem that states that if you have a local minimum of a function and that function is strictly convex ($\Leftrightarrow$ it is positive definite), then the local minimum is in fact a global minimum. But in this case we only know that the equations are extrema of S. Can anyone shed his/her light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't yet quite conclude $S$ has a unique global minimum: for instance the one-dimensional function $S(\lambda) = e^\lambda$ has positive-definite Hessian but no global minimum.

You *can* conclude any of the following:

- Every critical point of $S$ is a strict *local* minimum.
- $S$ has at most one such critical point. In addition to the positive-definiteness of $S$, this requires that $S$ be defined on a convex set (in this case $\mathbb{R}^n$). Let $\lambda^1$ and $\lambda^2$ be two distinct critical points, and draw the line $\gamma(t) = t\lambda_2 + (1-t)\lambda_1$ between them. Then $$\frac{d^2 S(\gamma(t))}{dt^2} = (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^T\, HS(\gamma[t])\, (\lambda_2-\lambda_1) \geq 0$$ so $$\frac{d S(\gamma(t))}{dt}(t) = \frac{d S(\gamma(t))}{dt}(0) + \int_0^t \frac{d^2 S(\gamma(t))}{dt^2}(s)\,ds \geq \frac{d S(\gamma(t))}{dt}(0) = 0.$$
  Similarly $$\frac{d S(\gamma(t))}{dt} \leq \frac{d S(\gamma(t))}{dt}(1) = 0$$
  and $S(\gamma)$ is constant, contradicting the fact that $\lambda^1$ must be a strict minimum.
- Any local minimum of $S$ is a global minimum. A calculation along a path much as the one above shows that if $\lambda^1$ is a local minimum and $\lambda^2$ is any point, $S(\lambda^2) \geq S(\lambda^1)$.
- Let $g(a)$ be the sub-level-set of $S$, i.e. $$g(a)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R^n}\vert S(\lambda) \leq a\}.$$ If $g(a)$ is nonempty and bounded for some $a$, then $S$ has exactly one critical point, which is the global minimum. This is because $S$ must attain its minimum on the compact set $g(a)$. Depending on the form of $S$, you may be able to show that $S(\lambda) \to \infty$ as $\|\lambda\| \to \infty$ and then use this fact to prove that a global minimum of $S$ must exist.

Comment: +1 for elaborate answer. I do find that the second derivative of $S$ is strictly positive on a certain domain and also positive definite (related to second derivatives) on this specific domain. May I then conclude that because the second derivative is positive, the equations are local minima and by convexity that they form a global minimum?

Comment: In the case of your counterexample $S(\lambda) = e^{\lambda}$, isn't the problem that you don't have any extrema?

Comment: Yes, if you have a solution to $\nabla S = 0$, then that is a global minimum of $S$. I've added a bullet above.

Comment: there is still a problem: I only have an implicit equation for $\lambda$ from $\nabla S$, of which I actually want to prove the existence of solutions. This now seems like a circular argument to me, don't you think?

Comment: Yes. You need to show that $S\to\infty$ as $\|\lambda\| \to \infty$.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on the last bullet (or gave a reference in which this is treated? I don't really understand why S must attain a minimum on a compact set and why this is the global minimum when $S\rightarrow \infty$ as $|\lambda| \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: *Any* continuous real-valued function on a compact set attains its maximum and minimum on that set. This is the content of the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: If $S\to \infty$ as $\|\lambda\|\to\infty$ this guarantees that $g(a)$ is bounded, and hence compact, for any $a$ (and thus at least one $a$).